# Как урезать строку?

Tags: строки, qt, c++

Пример строки:

```
|word1|word2|word3|
```

Строка создается за такими правилами:

- обязательно должна начинаться с |, но не обязательно заканчиваться |
- число слов может быть разное
- слова разделенные |

Код:

```
 QString s("|word1|word2|word3|");
 s.mid(s.lastIndexOf('|'));
```

Как видно я получу |word1|word2|word3

А хочу получить |word1|word2|

Если все слова удалены, то в результате, должен быть |, тоесть |word1 -> |

Если бы исходная строка была без последнего символа |, то ответ был бы правильным, но она может иметь такой последний символ и не иметь.

В качестве варианта рассматривал QStringList, но в этом случаи слишком уж много лишних операций.

Также я думаю, что можно начать поиск с 2-ого символа с конца, но как это прописать?

Answer (score 2):

С QStringList действий как раз немного:

```
QString src("|word1|word2|word3|");
QStringList parts = src.split("|", QString::SkipEmptyParts);
/* и здесь уже делаем с parts что в голову придёт */
```

Comment: @klopp действий мало и скорости мало. т.к теперь нужно объединять элементы с 0 по n-2. А для этого опять проходи по циклу и много перевыделений памяти.

Comment: @andrey3: Вы уже отпрофилировали и нашли, что именно это место — bottleneck? Сколько тысяч раз в секунду вызывается у вас этот код?

Comment: @VladD я не могу точно сказать сколько раз. Но, скажем так, он используется в потоках очень активно. Если бы был метод lastIndexOf, где поиск с конца можно было начать с символа 2-ого символа (с конца), то тогда проблема бы решилась

Comment: "Скажем так", "очень активно" - не аргумент ни разу. Вот когда профайлер покажет, что именно этот код хоть сколько-то существенное время по сравнению с другим отжирает, вот тогда и можно будет думать дальше. Но что-то мне подсказывает, что само по себе использование QString уже говорит о том, что работа со строками никак не будет узким местом в принципе...

Comment: @andrey3: В крайнем случае вы можете просто найти нужную позицию руками, проверяя символы с конца. Но могу поспорить, что распарсить строку на части вам всё равно рано или поздно придётся, так что это лишняя работа. Пересмотрите код, скорее всего строка должна быть поделена на части сразу же после чтения её из файла/потока/откуда-там-она-берётся.

Comment: @VladD нужно просто вывести нужную часть строки на экран. Других действий с нею не будет происходит. Как вариант, думаю сначала использовать метод mid, чтобы убрать последний символ со строки, а затем lastIndexOf и опять mid для получения нужной части. Но происходит 2 переопределения памяти. Хочется один.

Comment: @andrey3: **вывести на экран**? Тогда не морочьте нам голову и идите через `StringList`. Вы, надеюсь, понимаете, что любая операция ввода-вывода в тысячи раз медленнее любой аллокации.

Нет, вы всё же отпрофилируйте. Правда.

Answer (score 0):

> Также я думаю, что можно начать поиск с 2-ого символа с конца, но как это прописать?

нужно просто посмотреть в документацию

```
QString s("|word1|word2|word3|");
s.mid(s.lastIndexOf('|', -2));
```

А вот когда нужен будет QStringList  - вот тогда и используйте его.